# How can I set the owner component a view?

Tags: sapui5

If I create a view and its controller in run time how can I connect it to a component while when I call `getOwnerComponent` it returns the component.

I can not found any `setOwnerComponent` for the controller or view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by running the code that creates the new view inside a "runAsOwner" call:

```js
var oView = oComponent.runAsOwner(function() {
  return sap.ui.xmlview("myView", {
     // view info
  });
});
```

You can see more information about the runAsOwner function [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Component.html#runAsOwner). I have also made a small fiddle to demonstrate this: https://jsfiddle.net/93mx0yvt/21/.